# Axios cancelToken cancel and delete while sending multi requests strange behavior

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I'm using axios cancelToken in order to cancel requests made by the user in order to not overload the api. But for some reason I'm struggling to understand why it works only for odd number of requests and if the object of the remains with a reference. In the following code I'm experiencing glitches, it misses most of the requests.

some of the functions are mutations some actions

```
async add({ dispatch, commit, state }, { item }) {
    addLoader({id:item.id});
    let { data } = await this.$axios.get("/add", {
      params: item,
      cancelToken: state.loaders[item.id].token,
    });
     //commit adding the item
  },

// every token is being created here
function createToken(id = null) {
  let cancelToken = null;
  cancelToken = this.$axios.CancelToken.source();

  return cancelToken;
}
 addLoader(state, { id }) {
    if (state.loaders[id]) {
      state.loaders[id].cancel();
    }
    state.loaders = {
      ...state.loaders,
      [id]: createToken.call(this),
    };
  },

removeLoader(state, { id }) {
    let loadersObj;
    let loader;
    if (state.loaders[id]) {
      loadersObj = { ...state.loaders };
      loaders[id].cancel();
      delete loaders[id];
      // cannot delete before keeping a reference for some reason
      // loader = loadersObj[id];
      // loader.cancel();
      // delete loadersObj[id];
      ////////////////////////
      state.loaders = loadersObj;
    } else {
      console.log("didnt find any loader", id);
    }
  },
```

So basically if I'm using the code that i've marked it works perfectly for odd number of requets:
request1 - canceled
request2 - canceled
request3 - passed

when in even number of requests:
request1 - canceled
request2 - canceled

Appreciate it if you can guide me through to understand exactly what am I missing.
Thanks.

Comment: `[id]: createToken.call(this)` why do you call the cancel immediately? There's something fishy in your code, plus you forgot to show the call to Axios.

Comment: how do you propose to do it? i'll edit the post